# Compute a running count in sqlite

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I would like to know how to compute a running count in **SQLite** as follows

Given the following table:

```
id | value
-- | -----
 A |    10
 A |    20
 B |    40
 A |    15
 B |    20
 C |    30
```

I would like to get the following table:

```
id | value | running_count
-- | ----- | -------------
 A |    10 |             1
 A |    20 |             2
 B |    40 |             1
 A |    15 |             3
 B |    20 |             2
 C |    30 |             1
```

Where, for example, the row with id = A and value = 15 has a running_count = 3 because this is the 3rd row with an ID of A.

Note: this solution should work for arbitrarily large tables. Thanks.

Comment: I'd recommend that you do that math in the application layer as SQLite does not have solid dense/rank/row_number() over() functions. You could try this if suitable to your dataset: `select *, (select count(*) + 1 from test where id = a.id and value < a.value) as running_count from test a order by a.id, a.value;`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm just learning SQLite and I guess that what I get from this is that SQLite is not suited for more involved queries.

Comment: SQLite is not appropriate for all situations. It has areas where it shines. If you foresee using a lot of simultaneous reads and writes, querying ranks etc., a database like PostgreSQL or MySQL/MariaDB might be quite suitable.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I went for SQLite because I needed something with very little overhead where the database was just stored in a file. It seemed that SQLite offered that whereas the other solutions seem to require a server to be running.

Comment: Great. I believe you had the right thought process and you can continue running SQLite. It's pretty good for many things (https://sqlite.org/whentouse.html). Your application code can compensate for things SQLite is inherently not so amazing at. Keep on using SQLite to see how far you can stretch it for your project. In relative short time you will be able to determine its suitability for your particular use case.

Answer (score 1):

Alas, SQLite doesn't support window functions.  You can do this with a correlated subquery.  However, you need a proper *ordering* column.  In SQLite, I think you can use `rowid`:

```
select t.*,
       (select count(*)
        from t t2
        where t2.id = t.id and t2.rowid <= t.rowid
       ) as running_count
from t;
```